# Using Symfony Form 2.3 in Silex

Tags: php, symfony-forms, silex

I'm trying to build a Symfony form (in Silex) by name. Using the configuration below, I believe I should be able to call `$form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder('address');`, however the FormRegistry cannot find a form of this type.

```php
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeExtensionInterface;

class AddressType extends AbstractType implements FormTypeExtensionInterface
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'address';
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('addressee', 'text');
        // .. fields ..
        $builder->add('country', 'text');
    }

    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return 'form';
    }
}
```

This is then added to the form registry using the `form.type.extensions` provider:

```php
$app['form.type.extensions'] = $app->share($app->extend('form.type.extensions', function($extensions) use ($app) {
    $extensions[] = new AddressType();

    return $extensions;
}));
```

Is there something else I need to do or a different way of building the form in this way?

Comment: Does your address type class have a function getParent() which returns 'form'?

Answer (score 4):

Why not use direct

```
$app['form.factory']->createBuilder('Namespace\\Form\\Types\\Form')
```

Comment: This was by far the best and simplest answer for me. It worked like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

First, sorry for my poor english. :)

I think you should extend `form.extensions`, instead of `form.type.extensions`.

Something like this:

```
    $app['form.extensions'] = $app->share($app->extend('form.extensions',
                    function($extensions) use ($app) {
                        $extensions[] = new MyTypesExtension();

                        return $extensions;
                    }));
```

Then your class `MyTypesExtension` should look like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractExtension;

class MyTypesExtension extends AbstractExtension
{

    protected function loadTypes()
    {
        return array(
            new AddressType(),
            //Others custom types...

        );

    }

}
```

Now, you can retrieve your custom type this way:

```
$app['form.factory']->createBuilder('address')->getForm();
```

Enjoy it!

Answer (score 1):

I see, this question is quite old but:

What you do is creating a new Form Type not extending an existing one, so the correct way to register it to add it to the 'form.types'. (Remember: form type extension is adding something to the existing types so for the future all instance will have that new 'feature'. Here you are creating a custom form type.)

```
$app['form.types'] = $app->share($app->extend('form.types', function ($types) use ($app) {
   $types[] = new AddressType();
   return $types;
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think when you are coming from Symfony to Silex form.type.extension can be misleading.

From Symfony [How to Create a Form Type Extension](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/form/create_form_type_extension.html):

- You want to add a generic feature to several types (such as adding a "help" text to every field type);
- You want to add a specific feature to a single type (such as adding a "download" feature to the "file" field type).

So as your code shows you want to add a FormType which exists in Symfony but you would use the [FormServiceProvider](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/form.html#usage) in Silex without defining an `AbstractType` and just use the `form.factory` service as shown in this example:

In your `app.php`:

```
use Silex\Provider\FormServiceProvider;
$app->register(new FormServiceProvider());
```

In your controller/action:

```
$form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder('form', $data)
    ->add('name')
    ->add('email')
    ->add('gender', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => array(1 => 'male', 2 => 'female'),
        'expanded' => true,
    ))
    ->getForm()
;
```